# How to improve the performance of following code in python Dataframe, if possible please mention the order of complexity :

Tags: python, function, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

The code below is working fine, but would like to improve the performance of the code.

Could we do it by indexing or is there any other way.

I'm trying to achieve to copy 40 one-hot encoders fields in to single column.

```
def soil_typ(row):
    if row['Soil_Type1'] == 1:
        return 1
    elif row['Soil_Type2'] == 1:
        return 2
    elif row['Soil_Type3'] == 1:
        return 3
    elif row['Soil_Type4'] == 1:
        return 4
    elif row['Soil_Type5'] == 1:
        return 5
    elif row['Soil_Type6'] == 1:
        return 6
    elif row['Soil_Type7'] == 1:
        return 7
    elif row['Soil_Type8'] == 1:
        return 8
    elif row['Soil_Type9'] == 1:
        return 9
    elif row['Soil_Type10'] == 1:
        return 10
    elif row['Soil_Type11'] == 1:
        return 11
    elif row['Soil_Type12'] == 1:
        return 12
    elif row['Soil_Type13'] == 1:
        return 13
    elif row['Soil_Type14'] == 1:
        return 14
    elif row['Soil_Type15'] == 1:
        return 15
    elif row['Soil_Type16'] == 1:
        return 16
    elif row['Soil_Type17'] == 1:
        return 17
    elif row['Soil_Type18'] == 1:
        return 18
    elif row['Soil_Type19'] == 1:
        return 19
    elif row['Soil_Type20'] == 1:
        return 20
    elif row['Soil_Type21'] == 1:
        return 21
    elif row['Soil_Type23'] == 1:
        return 22
    elif row['Soil_Type23'] == 1:
        return 23
    elif row['Soil_Type24'] == 1:
        return 24
    elif row['Soil_Type25'] == 1:
        return 25
    elif row['Soil_Type26'] == 1:
        return 26
    elif row['Soil_Type27'] == 1:
        return 27
    elif row['Soil_Type28'] == 1:
        return 28
    elif row['Soil_Type29'] == 1:
        return 29
    elif row['Soil_Type30'] == 1:
        return 30
    elif row['Soil_Type31'] == 1:
        return 31
    elif row['Soil_Type32'] == 1:
        return 32
    elif row['Soil_Type33'] == 1:
        return 33
    elif row['Soil_Type34'] == 1:
        return 34
    elif row['Soil_Type35'] == 1:
        return 35
    elif row['Soil_Type36'] == 1:
        return 36
    elif row['Soil_Type37'] == 1:
        return 37
    elif row['Soil_Type38'] == 1:
        return 38
    elif row['Soil_Type39'] == 1:
        return 39
    elif row['Soil_Type40'] == 1:
        return 40
    else:
        return 0
```

After this I've applied this function to create a new variable as below:

```
data_train['Soil'] = [soil_typ(row_[1]) for row_ in data_train.iterrows()]
```

The dataset contains almost 1.5 million records

The code above is working one, but would like to explore the performance of this piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to repeat a lot of the same code here. Steps explained after the code with "#".

```
n = 40

def soil_typ(row):
    for x in range(n+1):             # iters through a list of values and returns n+1
        y = 'Soil_Type%s' % x        # translates integer to string (label)
        if row[y] == True:           # value 1 is equal to "True"; less confusing if 
                                     # false or true being used here during a 0/1 com-
                                     # parison.
            return x
        else:
            return 0

.. code snippet ..
```